# GWT How to style CellList background

Tags: css, gwt, celllist

So I am providing the resources for my celllist via the constructor. Everything seems to work, I have provided my own style sheet:

```
.cellListWidget {
 color: #021650;
 background-color: #021650;
}

.cellListEvenItem {
cursor: pointer;
zoom: 1;
background: red;
}

.cellListOddItem {
cursor: pointer;
zoom: 1;
background: blue;
}

.cellListKeyboardSelectedItem {
background: #ffc;
}

.cellListSelectedItem {
background-color: green;
color: white;
height: auto;
overflow: visible;
}
```

I must not understand it quite right because the background color I tried to set for the widget does not seem to take any effect. The rest of the styles work though, even item, odd item, selected item, etc.

Just to clarify, I want to change the color of the whole column this list is on, it items in the list are obviously styled, but the list takes up more vertical space than there are items, so where there are no items, is just a grey color which I want to change.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with the styling but that the cell list is not taking up all the vertical space in the dockpanellayout that it is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to not style the cell list, but the flowpanel that the cell list was on.